# how do you force a specific version of crystal reports to be compiled in a project?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

On the development machine, I have two version of crystal reports installed, 11.5 and 13.0

On our development server, I have the 11.5 crystal runtime installed, and a previous project loads fine (it generates a crystal report and downloads it to the users pc)

The current project I'm working on is an c# web form application (it's old).  When I load up the website on my local development machine, it loads up fine.

When I publish the website to the development server, I get the following error message:

> *Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified*

It looks like the references in the project using crystal is set correctly, because when I open up the csproj file in notepad, I get the following

```
<Reference Include="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

When i check the properties pane of the crystal references, it points to the GAC, but when I follow the GAC reference, it looks like it's just 11.5 crystal dll's in there.

The fact that I have 11.5 in the project references, where does the project know to even pick up the 13.0 version of crystal, and how do I get it to compile with 11.5?

I will uninstall 13.0 if I have to, but surely there is a way to do this?

Comment: Going over my check ins, Crystal automatically added an entry in my web.config that references the new version of the crystal dll's, as soon as it was pulled out, it came together.  How annoying